# Trying to remove a bit.ly URL at the end of a SQL string

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

Trying to remove a http://bit.ly URL at the end of a SQL string using TRIM or REPLACE, etc.

I have tried `TRIM`, `REPLACE` and a few others.

Here is an example of what the string is:

> "A FLOOD WARNING has been issued for Scott County. Flooding over a large area or river is imminent or occurring. http://example.com/2Vzjxbe"

So what I'm need to do is search the string for "http" and then remove everything from "h" in http and after. So the resulting string would be:

> "A FLOOD WARNING has been issued for Scott County. Flooding over a large area or river is imminent or occurring."

I'm grabbing a variable called `message` from outgoing_messages table

Comment: Your question and example URL are not consistent.

Comment: Will your string contain any other URLs?

Comment: Gordon, Yes there will alway be a url. Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you doing this in SQL or in ColdFusion?

Answer (score 3):

if the URL is always at the end of the string plus you don't want to change the query then you can create a new string using a regex replace

```
<cfset stringWithoutLink = reReplaceNoCase(string, "\s*https?://.+$", "", "all") />
```

if the URL is not always at the end of the string it can be tricky since there is some ambiguity as to what characters are part of the URL versus text that may be right up against it. Here is a reasonable example and you can tweak the character considered part of the url (note: if simplified url like from bit.ly then this is easier)

```
<cfset stringWithoutLink = reReplaceNoCase(string, "\s*https?://[a-z0-9/_-]+", "", "all") />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left()` with `charindex()` :

```
select left(col, charindex('http://', col + 'http://') - 1)
from table t;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding! I tried it but I get the following error when I try to run: ERROR: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 
'http://' to data type int. Error Code: 245

Comment: I actually changed it to left(message, charindex('http://', message) - 1) and it work!!! Is there any issue with talking out 'http://'? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use string manipulation -- `left()` and `charindex()`:

```
select left(str, charindex('http://', str + 'http://') - 1)
from (values ('A FLOOD WARNING has been issued for Scott County. Flooding over a large area or river is imminent or occurring. http://URL.com/2Vzjxbe')) v(str)
```

Note that this adds `'http://'` to the string being searched.  The code will work on strings with no URL reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding! I tried it but I get the following error when I try to run: ERROR: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 
'http://' to data type int. Error Code: 245

Comment: I actually changed it to left(message, charindex('http://', message) - 1) and it work!!! Is there any issue with talking out 'http://'? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Scott . . . The code will fail if no URL is there.  If it is always there, then no problem.

Comment: Do you know why the original code was causing an error? Thanks

Comment: @Scott . . . It did not cause an error when I ran it.  In SQL Server, `+` can mean either string concatenation or addition.  If any argument is a number, then it is interpreted as addition.  For instance, if you wrote `charindex('http://', str) + 'http://'` rather than `charindex('http://', str + 'http://')`.

Comment: It's actually working now.... didn't change anything. Thank you so much for the help, it is greatly appreciated!!!!